App Entry Not Found Error After Installing Firebase with Yarn in React Native
I am facing an issue in my React Native + expo app after trying to install Firebase using Yarn. After running the yarn add firebase command, my app stopped working, and I now see the following error on my phone emulation:
App entry not found.

I followed a Firebase tutorial and installed the Firebase SDK using yarn add firebase.
I restarted the development server using yarn start and react-native run-android, but the error persists.
I tried clearing the cache using yarn cache clean, but the issue remains.
My env
"expo": "~52.0.20",
"firebase": "^11.1.0",
"react": "18.3.1",
"react-native": "0.76.5",

